# Is it possible to negatively filter spells in D&D Beyond?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, online-resources, dnd-beyond

I would like to filter for all spells on the ranger spell list that aren't on the druid spell list; in other words, all ranger spells, unless it is a druid spell.

Is this possible with D&D Beyond as it currently stands, without manually working out the difference between the two?

The requested filter will be discussed in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156522/45088).

Comment: You may wish to ask for the "ranger non-druid" spells as a separate question. It may not be super popular, but it is certainly workable for the stack. If you work this list out for yourself you could even ask and self answer to help other who have your (specific) problem later.

Comment: @Someone_Evil I specifically give an example just so it's clear what's needed. I'll spin up a question for it and link it here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible to search DND Beyond for spells available to Rangers that are not also available to Druids.
*(09/19/2019)*

DND Beyond lets you filter spells by class. The various classes can either be included in the search results or be exempted from them by ticking the check mark of the appropriate radio button.

However, a google search for “Ranger only spells” yielded useful results.

Comment: I've edited out the images from your post again. You made the right choice by removing them the first time. They make the post very very hard to read and people know what a google search looks like, there's no reason to show a picture of one. And if you found a Google result that was relevant here, the best procedure would be to link to that source and/or quote the relevant parts.

Comment: Okay, i received more upvotes with the pictures, only time will tell.

Comment: I would wager that the votes were in spite of the pictures, not because of them. Your answer is correct and correct answers tend to get upvotes over time. But the pictures make it much less appealing and add nothing to the post.

Comment: I'm wary of the google search suggestion if it leads to content that isn't above board. If you can provide a legitimate site that provides the answer, that's one thing, but the generic google search prevent me keeping my upvote. I do agree that the image made it impossible read.

Comment: Hm, interesting - reason I had the picture was to show the resulting info (which was accurate).

Comment: Interesting that your pictures make it seem like you can search multiple classes at once, but I cannot find a way to do this. Perhaps it is only a feature of the mobile application