# What spells are on the ranger spell list and not the druid spell list?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, ranger

As I have requested in [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156513/45088) question, what spells are on the ranger spell list and not on the druid spell list?

I am most interested in source books as opposed to adventure books, such as the PHB, XGtE, and the DMG. Unofficial material and Unearthed Arcana should not be included.

This should only include base spell lists; discussion on subclass expanded spell lists is not needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Here is the list I came up with

1st level:

- [*alarm*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alarm)
- [*ensnaring strike*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ensnaring-strike)
- [*hail of thorns*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hail-of-thorns)
- [*hunter's mark*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark)
- [*zephyr strike*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/zephyr-strike)

2nd level:

- [*cordon of arrows*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cordon-of-arrows)
- [*silence*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silence)

3rd level:

- [*conjure barrage*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-barrage)
- [*lightning arrow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/lightning-arrow)
- [*nondetection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/nondetection)

5th level:

- [*conjure volley*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-volley)
- [*steel wind strike*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/steel-wind-strike)
- [*swift quiver*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/swift-quiver)

I constructed this list by searching for all spells which are *both* Druid and Ranger spells and then counted (individually, one-by-one) the spells which were Ranger exclusive.

Comment: @Rykara To be fair I found no *easy* way of searching for this, and used my own personal spreadsheets as well as a third party site

Comment: Are any of the new Tasha's spells relevant for this list?

Comment: @Someone I'll add new spells within the next 24 hours. Might end up just making this a community wiki like some of my other list answers

Comment: @Someone_Evil I know 24 hours does not equal 240 hours *but*... Apparently *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* does not impact this list at all